# Re-open deleted Git branch

Tags: git, version-control, merge, git-flow, pull-request

I'm using [git flow](http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/) for my project and I had to make a `hotfix` branch. When it was completed, I made a pull request to merge it into `master` and then deleted the branch.

I've since realized that it also needed to be merged into `develop`. However, I deleted the branch from the remote as well as from my PC. Is there any way I can reopen the branch to make a pull request to merge it to `develop`?

I'd like to avoid merging `master` into `develop` since it also includes other changes that I've made in release branches (bumping version numbers, etc).

Or perhaps there is another, better solution? In general, what is a good practice to use git flow with pull requests?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Deleting a branch just removes the label that was attached to the commit. The commit that used to be the head of the branch is still present. You just need to put the label back.

If you merged `hotfix` into `master` and it created a merge commit at `aabbcc`, then you can resurrect `hotfix` using:

```
git branch hotfix aabbcc^2
```

The `^2` is shorthand for "the second parent". If you didn't create a merge commit, then just re-create `hotfix` using the last of its commits:

```
git branch hotfix ddeeff
```

Of course, if you know `ddeeff` even in the case of a merge commit above, you can use the last commit directly.

Comment: Thanks, Greg. I'll accept your answer after I try this out tomorrow. I knew it should be easy to do, but I couldn't find the documentation.

Comment: The checking out to the last commit of the closed branch and creating branch from it, resolved my problem. Very easy and unexpedtedly obvious workaround. Thanks!

Comment: This seems to work if I don't completely wipe out my local repo. If I delete my local repo, re-clone using the repo URL and then attempt to re-create a remote branch that was deleted using a pull request, I can only use the merge commit on master, not the last commit on the actual deleted branch, unless I'm missing something here.

Comment: Thanks. In a pull request, I can still see the last commit SHA in the deleted remote branch even though the branch no longer exists. Is there still no way to leverage this info to recreate the branch?